# mmap with /dev/input/event*

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

does anyone know if mmap (in c++/c) works with /dev/input/event* device files? I have been having trouble getting it to work. I keep getting an error 19 (No such device) error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `/dev/input/event*` devices are character devices, not block devices. Character devices can't be memory-mapped, because they don't contain persistent data at specific locations. (Once you read something out of the device, it's gone.)

Comment: Okay, is it possible to have two processes read from the same event file and extract the same events?